# Raising an Alert with THROW

Tags: sql-server, alerts, raiserror

It seems to me that SQL THROW is missing a crucial feature that `RAISERROR` has, and that is the abilty to use `WITH LOG` so that an Alert can be fired when the error number is logged in the Application log.

Is there a simple way to do this that is escaping me or do I still have to rely on the more cumbersome `RAISERROR` and `sp_addmessage` SP?

I would like to be able to notify an Operator through an Alert using `THROW` in a `CATCH` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `THROW` is missing some `RAISERROR` functionality, including `WITH LOG`. I blogged about this back when SQL Server 2012 was still in beta, and no changes have been made since:

- [SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : Exploring THROW](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/22/sql-server-v-next-denali-exploring-throw)

However, you don't need to use `sp_addmessage` to send `RAISERROR` messages to the log, unless you need a custom message number outside of 50000:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(32) = 'friend';
RAISERROR(N'What happened %s?', 19, 1, @s) WITH LOG;
```

Results:

> [image]

Reading the guts of the question again, you probably do want to use `sp_addmessage` to achieve your ultimate goal. I shouldn't have tried to separate the logging on its own from that (50000 doesn't help much if you have other errors getting logged and want different alerts).

Example of putting the error number into the *text* for the message raised by `RAISERROR`:

```
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @err INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
  RAISERROR(N'What happened %d?', 19, 1, @err) WITH LOG;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. As I suspected. i was just hoping I was missing something or at perhaps there was another way that I was unaware of. THROW is a sweet little deal except for that one missing feature. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thinking I may resort to using capturing @@error into a variable or using ERRORNUMBER() to log the error into a table. This might be more practical for my purposes anyway. I wonder, is it possible to insert the @@error data into a RAISERROR? Hmmm

Comment: You can easily put ERROR_NUMBER() into the message text, but not the actual error number raised by RAISERROR. Logging somewhere other than the error log, and having a different background process poll that for new errors, seems simpler and more reliable to me.